# XML document structures must start and end within the same entity android studio Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[XML document structures must start and end within the same entity android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8cP6.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. Also it looks like it's `activity_main.xml` that has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got an error on the activity_main.xml file.

Look for a typo, or any unclosed tag